# how to aggregate time in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, timestamp, string-aggregation

I have a column in a large csv file that has timestamps in the format of %H:%M:%S. What's the best way to get the aggregation(like mean, median, 25%, 75%, etc) from the list of timestamps.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'value': [5, 4, 3], 'time1':['9:30:41', '10:00:56', '13:01:09']})
```

Comment: How do you want to aggregate them ? in minutes, hours, exact time..?

Comment: better in timestamp

Answer (score 1):

You can use `time delta` to convert to the string to time period, it will allow `arithmetic operation` of addition and subtraction on timestamp,

```
df.time1 = pd.to_timedelta(df.time1)
df.sum()
```

Out:

```
key                  abc
time1    1 days 08:32:46
value                 12
dtype: object
```

But for multiplication and division includes `mean and other`, you can convert the `timestamp to seconds` and apply

```
df.time1 = pd.to_timedelta(df.time1)/np.timedelta64(1, 's')
```

Out:

```
    key time1   value
0   a   34241.0 5
1   b   36056.0 4
2   c   46869.0 3
```

Once your required operation is done, you can convert back to time stamp with `pd.to_timedelta with 'seconds' u`nit

```
pd.to_timedelta(df.time1,unit='s')
```

Out:

```
0   09:30:41
1   10:00:56
2   13:01:09
Name: time1, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```